# What's the time complexity of doubling 1 until N?

Tags: algorithm, time-complexity

```
def function(N):
    foo = 1
    while foo < N:
         foo *= 2
    return foo
```

I think it's O(log N), since foo is being multiplied by a constant amount?

Comment: You are correct.

Comment: O(N*loglogN) -- right shift 32 bits, check for 0, then by 16, then 8, etc.

Comment: O(1) -- Convert to float, then play with the exponent.  (That is, let that conversion do a "normalize" to discover number of leading 0s.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is something you can easily show by the definition of logarithm. For simplicity we consider base 2 logarithm (all log bases are equivalent in big-O notation since they are all within a constant factor of each other).

```
log2 n = k
```

means:

```
2 ** k = n
```

but `2 ** k` is actually `2 * 2 * 2 ... * 2` (`k` times) -- for integer `k`.
For any given `n`, `k` may not be integer, but you can safely consider the next positive integer `k` as that guarantees that `2 ** k` is larger than `n`.

So, the number of `* 2` operation needed to go from `1` to `n` is `k` (within unity).